# Want to permanently mount Kernel-Driver into System

Tags: linux, debian, linux-device-driver, insmod

I wrote my own kernel driver for a usb-device. After I compile it with make, I have the kernelobejct file usbdriver.ko and with sudo insmod usbdriver.ko I can install and then use it.
But if I restart my Debian, I need to do do insmod again to use it ...
How can i mount/install that driver permanently into the system, so that it loads when the os is starting? And how can I also grant other users than only root to access the asscoiated device-files under /dev/usbdriver0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy your driver to `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/` and add it to `/etc/modules`: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html.
2. I don't know but I think it's in the source code somewhere.

Comment: ok so I can autoload it at startup, but cant manage rights that way. I read something about putting a file in /etc/udev/rules.d but i dont know how to write such a file ... :(

Comment: Ok i found a working solution: created the file /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbdriver.rules with this line
SYSFS{idVendor}=="1337", SYSFS{idProduct}=="4242", MODE="0660",GROUP="developer"